# cannot create a Connection between java servlet and database using Tomcat9

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, servlets, jdbc

I created a web application using Tomcat 9 running on Linux machine. When I try to create connection beetwen ths servlet and the database, program stops itself (maybe servlet waits for something, no error and Servlet doesnt print line after the line where I try to create connection).

```
    Connection con=null;
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    out.println("<before create connection");
    con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://192.168.0.130:5432/mydb","root", "root");
out.println("connection created");
```

There was no problem when I run the program on my pc in localhost (using tomcat 8). Problem was born when I move on the remote server.

I follow instruction on https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources and I've modified web.xml file,
with

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>
    Resource reference to a factory for java.sql.Connection
    instances that may be used for talking to a particular
    database that is configured in the <Context>
    configuration for the web application.
  </description>
  <res-ref-name>
    jdbc/EmployeeDB
  </res-ref-name>
  <res-type>
    javax.sql.DataSource
  </res-type>
  <res-auth>
    Container
  </res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

where instead of EmployeDB there is the name of my database. But nothing happens

Comment: check connectivity with  telnet 192.168.0.130 5432. Your program doesn't stop, it probably hangs waiting for a TimeOut to happen.

Comment: Can be many things, find your tomcat logs and have a look throught that.

Comment: 192.168.0.130 is an address in the private IP space.  If your remote server is off that network you will need a public IP for your server.